# Escape escape characters in spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring

Given a string, I want to replace all double slashes with one slash, and then all instances of `\n` with `-`. For instance, if I have this:

```
\\n\\nff
```

It should be converted to:

```
\n\nff
```

And then to:

```
--ff
```

---

I wrote this code:

```
shippingAddress = shippingAddress.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");
```

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("xx");
    String x = "enterchar17\\n\\n\\nenterchar17enterchar17\\n\\n\\n\\nenterchar17";
    System.out.println(x);
    x.replaceAll("\\n","\n");
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

This produces this output:

```
 xx
enterchar17\n\n\nenterchar17enterchar17\n\n\n\nenterchar17
enterchar17\n\n\nenterchar17enterchar17\n\n\n\nenterchar17
```

so it did not change. I need to escape escape char because somehow spring boot sends 2 slashes. What can i do?

i think JSON does think double as double. It doesn't get it escape?

```
"line1": "fasfsafasfsa\n\n\nff\n\tasas",
```

on postman, when i send request like this, \n is converted to "-"

but in postman when i send with double, it  cantconvert.

when i inspect to the page where i send request of string, i see this

```
line1
:
"enterchar17↵↵v↵↵enterchar17↵↵↵enterchar17"
```

on chromium

Answer (score 2):

I think you have java problem.  The line

```
x.replaceAll("\\n","\n");
```

should be

```
x = x.replaceAll("\\n","\n");
```

String is an immutable class. Therefore, the output from a method needs to be captured in a variable.